# Chrome Extension get local json with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I have a json with some data for a Chrome extension I'm making. The extension uses jQuery. I'm trying to read the data in my javascript though it doesn't work. I'm using `jQuery.getJSON`:

```
console.log("Start loading sets");
$.getJSON("AllSets.json", function (data) {
    console.log("done");
});
```

I get the "Start loading sets" call, but not "done". I read the `getJSON` is actually to get a JSON from a server using http, so that could explain why it doesn't work for local jsons. So what should I use to read the included json?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up a local web server.

Comment: I meant that the json is included with the extension, so everyone has their own copy.

Comment: How is the JSON stored in the extension? On the local file system?

Comment: Where are you calling this from? If it is from a content script, you will need to add AllSets.json to the web accessible resources section of your manifest and use [chrome.extension.getUrl](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) to get its path.

Comment: @Joel Spadin. Yes I'm calling this in a content script. And that worked, thanks! If you add it as an answer I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a resource in your extension from a content script, first add it to the ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section of your manifest, then use [chrome.extension.getUrl()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) to get a link to it. Then you can use an XMLHttpRequest (or your preferred wrapper around it) as usual.