# JavaScript fetch outputting error in console

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

```
fetch('info.json').then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error('Something went wrong with retrieving the info!');
});
```

The file 'info.json' is in the same directory as this javascript file, and when I run it on chrome using dev tools, the console outputs 'Something went wrong with retrieving the data!' I'm not sure how to fix this as this is my first time working with developer tools and unloading a package via extensions on chrome. Any help would be appreciated! For those curious, I'm trying to create an autofiller for a site and the 'info.json' file contains info like name, address, etc.

Comment: What do you see in the Network Tab of Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Not too sure this is still applicable, but have you tried something like suggested here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23398129/1427878 ?

Comment: In your `.catch()` block you discard the actual error message, so it will print `Something went wrong with retrieving the info!` for any error. Try adding a log like `console.error(error)` - without the error message it's hard to tell what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

This will make a request to https://example.com/info.json

You need to put this in your manifest:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "yourfolder/*"
  ],
```

Then in your script get the url

```
const myUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('yourFolder/info.json')

fetch(myUrl).then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error('Something went wrong with retrieving the info!');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Also, if you can explain, why does my chrome browser always refresh whenever I change code in my javascript file? There is a hot-reload.js file, but it reloads any page that I'm on, even if it's not related to the extension.

Comment: Really I don't know about that. I use web-ext https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext. For development